# Simplification of integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration, hyperbolic-functions

When dealing with hyperbolic functions, simplifying:
$$
2\pi\int_{-a}^a a \cdot \cosh^2\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)dx
$$
Yields:
$$
2\pi a\cdot \frac{a}{2}(2+\sinh 2)
$$

How is this possible?

Comment: I was going to edit the question. But the use of $a$ Confuses me slightly.

Comment: You can use the double "angle" identity or integrate by parts. Double "angle" is faster.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cosh(2u) = 2\cosh^2 u -1
$$
Thus we can let your integral be
$$
2\pi\int_{-a}^{a} a\cosh^2\left(x/a\right) dx= 2\pi a^2\int_{-1}^{1} \cosh^2(u)du
$$
Then using the identity I provide above you can proceed.

Comment: When i integrate cosh^2(x/a) i keep on getting the incorrect answer. Can you please provide step by step instructions on how you go about integrating cosh^2(x/a).

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this integral using $x=at$:
$$I = 2\pi a\cdot a \int_{-1}^1 \cosh^2 t dt.$$
Now we use definition of $\cosh$:
$$\cosh^2 t = \left(\frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2}\right)^2 = \frac14(e^{2t} + 2 + e^{-2t}),$$
and then
\begin{align}
I &= 2\pi a^2 \cdot\frac14 \int_{-1}^1 (e^{2t} + 2 + e^{-2t})\, dt = 2\pi a^2 \cdot\frac14 \left.\left(\frac12e^{2t} + 2t - \frac12 e^{-2t}\right)\right|_{t=-1}^{t=1} =\\&= 2\pi a^2 \cdot\frac14 \left(\frac12 e^2 + 2 - \frac12e^{-2} - \frac12e^{-2} - (-2) + \frac12 e^2\right)=\\
&=\frac12\pi a^2 (e^2 - e^{-2} + 4) = \pi a^2 \left(\frac{e^2 - e^{-2}}{2} + 2\right)=\pi a^2 (2 + \sinh 2)
\end{align}